# Using pip to install libraries, then the libraries aren't found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm quite new to programming, and I am trying to progress beyond Python's built-in libraries. When I tried to `pip install pandas` it seemed to work fine, but then when I attempted to use it I got an ImportError message: "No Module names 'pandas'". Am I missing something really obvious here?

Extra details: Python 3.6.0, Windows 10 home 64-bit, Asus Zenbook UX305, Accessing the internet from China.
[This is a screenshot showing my pip install of pandas and the readout from Thonny telling me "No Module names 'pandas'"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRTBB.png)

Comment: what are you using to write your scripts?

Comment: Try running `print(sys.version_info)` in that 'Thonny'

Comment: as your snapshot you have to use `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one copy of Python installed? Check it by typing "which python" in Terminal.

Comment: What is "thonny"? A brief google search revealed that it is some sort of ide meant for beginners, that comes with it's own interpreter. It's not using the interpreter that you've installed your libraries to, which seems to be an `anaconda` distribution.

Comment: @R.A.Munna That's another error ;)

Comment: @PiotrKamoda just got your point

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the Python version.
There are a few ways of doing this.

- `python3 -m pip install pandas`
- `pip3 install pandas`
- `<full-path-to-python> -m pip install pandas`

`python3 -m pip install` indicates that Python3's `pip` needs to be used for the installation, `pip3` also implies the same.

Post installation the best way to check if it's working or not is to open the basic Python shell in the terminal and trying to import it. If that works then you will know it is an issue with the configuration of the IDE you're using.

When using 3rd party IDEs like Thorny, many times they will have their own versions of Python which could throw things off. You would have to change the configuration to use your original Python in that case.